# Batch password change of all email in a cPanel account?

Tags: user-accounts, batch-processing

Does anyone know of a way to reset the password of one or more email addresses in a cPanel account from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't be done with native cpanel functions by the CLI, however you could do it via the cPanel API using [email::passwdpop](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiEmail#Email::passwdpop). The only other thing would be to write your own script to modify /home/user/etc/shadow. I would recommend the API.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll write a Python script to call the API.

Comment: Actually, you can. https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/UAPI+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Apasswd_pop

Example from docs:

cpapi1 --user=username Email passwdpop user 12345luggage 500 example.com